# unable to get checkout code

Tags: swift, xcode, rx-swift, carthage

I am trying to use RxSwift in playground and therefore I need RxSwift to be checked out, but `carthage update --platform iOS` only downloads the framework.

Do you know why and what to do?

Until then I will just git clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Playground pages say at the top, "Build the RxSwift-macOS scheme".  So first of all, you'll need to build the framework for `macOS` and not just `iOS`, as you're trying to do:

```
carthage update --platform macOS
```

Generally, if you're trying to get something to work, don't try to optimize until you've even gotten it to work. So don't even limit the platform yet and just get it to work in the simple case:

```
carthage update
```

As for ensuring that Carthage doesn't download pre-compiled frameworks, use the `--no-use-binaries` flag:

```
carthage update --no-use-binaries
```

However, that shouldn't be your problem, since Carthage will/should still checkout the framework's git repository to `Carthage/Checkouts/` in both cases.